# What is meant by the term "discrete" number with respect to the imaginary part of the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, differential-operators, riemann-hypothesis

The following link indicates the imaginary parts of the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ are "discrete" numbers.

[New Insight into Proving the Riemann Hypothesis](https://phys.org/news/2017-04-insight-math-million-dollar-problem-riemann.html)

What is meant by the term "discrete" number with respect to the imaginary part of the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$?

Comment: The zeros of $F(s) = \sin(1/s)$ accumulate at $s= 0$ therefore $F$ isn't analytic at $s=0$.

Comment: The adjective "discrete" does not apply to the individual zeros, it applies to the *set* of all zeros. A subset of a topological space inherits a topology, and a topological space is discrete if every subset is open, from which it follows a subset of a topological space is discrete if and only if every one of its points is isolated (is contained in an open subset that does not contain any of the other points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is that each of the zeros is [isolated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point).

Comment: as $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is entire